# Typed.js Speed Lagging

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, typed, typed.js

I'm using Typed.js and all is working as expected. However occasionally the typing speed will be far slower than expected. This is an issue for me because I am using a timeOut function to do something after the text has typed out.

Sometimes the typing speed is completely normal and sometimes it only types one letter a second, aka huge delay. How can I fix this?

Note: I have multiple Typed objects on the page. Here is one:

```js
var typed = new Typed('#typed-free', {
  stringsElement: '#typed-explain-free',
  backSpeed: 0,
  typeSpeed: 55,
  showCursor: false,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.0/typed.min.js" integrity="sha512-zKaK6G2LZC5YZTX0vKmD7xOwd1zrEEMal4zlTf5Ved/A1RrnW+qt8pWDfo7oz+xeChECS/P9dv6EDwwPwelFfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="typed-free"></div>
<div id='typingExplanation'>
  <div id="typed-explain-free">
    <p>Welcome this is an example of using Typed where it is lagging too much. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I have multiple Typed objects on the page` How many instances do you have? How large is the DOM in your page? The library itself works fine in isolation (as you can see in the example I edited in to your question), therefore I would assume the problem is due to weight of data within the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Rory! I have 3 instances running and the DOM is large. What can I do to improve that?

Comment: Were you finally able to fix the issue? We're also experiencing the same issue, although we only have one instance. From what we've seen it also tents to happen more frequently on screens with a high resolution.